# how to access timestamp in DataFrame pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Having downloaded data from yahoo for a stock using the `get_data_yahoo` I then want to access the time for each row... How do I do that?

One way I've kind of figured out to do this is:

```
it = stock.iterrows()
st0 = it.next()
resultIWant = st0[0].value # this gives what I want (almost)
print resultIWant
```

EDIT:

So basically I want something like `stock['Open']` but for time, smth like `stock['Time']` would be ideal..

some one asked for the output of `.head`

```
            Open  High   Low  Close  Volume  Adj Close
Date                                                  
2012-04-03  2.06  2.09  2.01   2.08  463200       2.08
2012-04-04  2.04  2.05  2.01   2.02  335600       2.02
```

Expected output from function:

```
print find_time(stock,2) # function I'm looking for
1333497600000000000      # resulting output
```

The expected output is the time from the last epoch for each of the dates in an array or some other way to get the time of each entry. The example code I gave gives me the results I want however if I want to get access to the 4th element the only way to do it would be to `.next` the iterator 4 times, this seems like a bad method.

First Question: Is there a more obvious way, what I'm doing doesn't seem like the best way to do this.

Second Question: What units is the result in? I think it's nanoseconds but not sure...

Comment: What do you want to do with these times, ultimately? Help us understand where you're going with this, and you'll get a clearer answer.

Comment: I want to subtract subtract stockTime[1] - stockTime[0] so I need the value of the first and the second element... ultimately i'm trying to build a candlestickchart and want to have the right widths for the bars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer I found in the end [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/pandas.pdf)

You can access the rows using `st.ix[index_val]` from section 5.2.8 of the reference.

ts = st.ix[2].Name

which returns a timestamp

`ts` is the same as the `st[0]` in the question

Answer (score 3):

Timestamps have a `time` method:

```
In [1]: t = pd.Timestamp('200101011300')

In [2]: t
Out[2]: <Timestamp: 2001-01-01 13:00:00>

In [3]: t.time()
Out[3]: datetime.time(13, 0)
```

The `value` is **nanoseconds** since midnight 1 January 1970 i.e. [unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) * 10 ** 9:

```
In [4]: t.value
Out[4]: 978354000000000000
```

Comment: hm.... but my question is with regards to how I get the Timestamp part of the stock out? I have no idea how to access it other than what I showed..

Comment: @evan54 it's not entirely clear on what the structure is of your DataFrame, an example would help a lot, e.g. the output of df.head(). Certainly you want to avoid using a for loop.

Comment: the output I expect is the same as from the code I've posted. I updated the question to include `.head` output and the expected output of the function I'm after... Hopefully that clears things up

Comment: Still not sure what you're asking, but if you have a function for one value, you can then use Series/DataFrame `apply` or index's `map`, e.g. `df.index.map(lambda t: t.value)` ?

Answer (score 3):

Just seen the question. But may be it is interesting to somebody.

In this case you can make next command:

```
stock['Time'] = stock.index
```

then you'll get new column `'Time'` cause your `Date` is the index. To convert the DateTime to Unix Time change to:

import numpy as np

stock['Time'] = stock.index.astype(np.int64).

Answer (score 0):

In fact each row contains a tuple contains index and data, so you might do this:

```
for index, row in stock.iterrows():
    print index
```

Comment: any way of accessing it out of a loop? I mean this is pretty much what I showed right? I want to get `stock['Time']` or something like that..

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: I posted what I expect, it is basically what the `.next` implementation outputs